# python regex - ConnectionProfile:Database:MSSQL

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the word in the middle
for example

```
ConnectionProfile:Database:MSSQL - result Database
```

Sometimes the text will be

```
ConnectionProfile:Database:Oracle:ServiceName - i need the string after ConnectionProfile: till the next :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the two examples provided, you may simply use string functions:

```
string = "ConnectionProfile:Database:MSSQL"

print(string.split(":")[1])
```

If `ConnectionProfile` happens to be somewhere else, you could try:

```
ConnectionProfile:([^:]+)
```

And take the first capture group, [**see regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/FNccQe/1/) for a demo.